# How to find the most probable pair of a string from a two-column dataset?

Tags: python, hashmap, nested

Given columns A and B,  how can I find the most probable item at column B each of the items at column A? What about something based on nested hash-maps? I want to do that in Python.

**INPUT:**

```
a,abd37534c7d9a2efb9465de931cd7055ffdb8879563ae98078d6d6d5
a,abd37534c7d9a2efb9465de931cd7055ffdb8879563ae98078d6d6d5
a,abd37534c7d9a2efb9465fghfghfghfghfghrewresdasdzfdghhgfhg
a,abd3753dfrtdgfdg563ae98078d6dfgfdgdfghdgasdaSADFBVFDGFD5
b,c681e18b81edaf2b66dd22376734dba5992e362bc3f91ab225854c17
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
a,abd37534c7d9a2efb9465de931cd7055ffdb8879563ae98078d6d6d5
b,c681e18b81edaf2b66dd22376734dba5992e362bc3f91ab225854c17
```

Comment: Define "most probable"

Comment: What does most probable mean? Do you mean most common?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: We all try to be nice on this forum. But I really think you're asking us to solve a homework problem. The answer to this will not likely help people understand Python any better. I'll answer anyway, but in the future, you may try to think through your problem a little more before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume "most probable" means the one with the highest occurrence for each {a,b}.

The following will likely work, though may have some syntax issues. In any case, it will give you an idea of how approach the problem (if not solve it for you).

```
tupleList = [('a','abd37534c7d9a2efb9465de931cd7055ffdb8879563ae98078d6d6d5'),
             ('a','abd37534c7d9a2efb9465de931cd7055ffdb8879563ae98078d6d6d5'),
             ('a','abd37534c7d9a2efb9465fghfghfghfghfghrewresdasdzfdghhgfhg'),
             ('a','abd3753dfrtdgfdg563ae98078d6dfgfdgdfghdgasdaSADFBVFDGFD5'),
             ('b','c681e18b81edaf2b66dd22376734dba5992e362bc3f91ab225854c17')]
# Load your list of a,blah into tupleList
myHashMap = {}
for col1, col2 in tupleList:
  if col1 not in myHashMap:
   myHashMap[col1] = {}
  if col2 not in myHashMap[col1]:
   myHashMap[col1][col2] = 0
  myHashMap[col1][col2] += 1

# Now iterate over to find the one with highest occurrence.
for col in myHashMap:
  maxKey = ''
  maxVal = 0
  for col2 in myHashMap[col1]:
    if myHashMap[col1][col2] > maxVal:
     maxVal = myHashMap[col1][col2]
     maxKey = col2
  print 'Most probable for %s is %s'%(col, maxKey)
```

Comment: apologise for the misunderstanding; what i meant was indeed "the one with the highest occurrence for each {a,b}." Also, I asked for a compact piece of code; something that uses build in functionality; btw, the above solution has syntax issues.